# C# Window Form Application: Is there a way to convert pdf into bitmap without using any third party library?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation

Sorry for another silly question here.
In Window Form Application: Is there a way to convert pdf image into bitmap without using any third party library?

Comment: No. You can always write your own conversion library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way of doing this: 
(Answering my own question again which I hope to share and help others in the future)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an instance of Bytescout.PDFRenderer.RasterRenderer object and register it.
        RasterRenderer renderer = new RasterRenderer();
        renderer.RegistrationName = "demo";
        renderer.RegistrationKey = "demo";

        // Load PDF document.
        renderer.LoadDocumentFromFile("multipage.pdf");

        for (int i = 0; i < renderer.GetPageCount(); i++)
        {
            // Render first page of the document to BMP image file.
            renderer.RenderPageToFile(i, RasterOutputFormat.BMP, "image" + i + ".bmp");
        }

        // Open the first output file in default image viewer.
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("image0.bmp");
    }
```

Using RasterRenderer and Bytescout.PDFRenderer will covert pdf into bmp file. What it is basically doing is it is "rendering" the bytes inside the file content for analyze with the PDF to convert it into bmp. 
(Credit to: bytescout)

Comment: I could not find bytescout DLL. Are you sure is this solution done without using any 3rd party library?

Comment: @deathrace You need that dll in order for it to work. The 3rd party libraries I used are RasterRenderer and Bytescout.PDFRenderer